# How to read Storyboard property "From" or "To" (etc.)

Tags: c#, animation, uwp, storyboard, dependency-properties

I have created `Storyboard` by code and during animation I need to read some `properties` like `From` and `To` etc. How to do this? I need to get these information because there are some needs to add/remove/edit effects during animation.

`Storyboard` uses `DoubleAnimation`. Following short example shows how I get some values but I cannot find the way how to get `From` or `To` values. `Timeline` (or `Storyboard`) do not have those values.

```
//GET EFFECT - THIS CALL GETS ADDED ANIMATION IN STORYBOARD 
Timeline TargetEffect = GetEffect(AnimationName, AnimationEffectType.Opacity);
//FROM
double From = (TargetElement as FrameworkElement).Opacity;
//DURATION
TimeSpan Duration = TargetEffect.Duration.TimeSpan;
//DELAY
TimeSpan Delay = TargetEffect.BeginTime.Value;
//REPEAT
RepeatBehavior Repeat = TargetEffect.RepeatBehavior;
//REVERSE
bool AutoReverse = TargetEffect.AutoReverse;
//FROM OR TO ????
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the reason you cannot access `From` and `To` is that you are using the general `Timeline` type, which does not have these properties defined (as only the derived types then define `From` and `To` with the specific type they animate). So to make it work, you will need to cast it to `DoubleAnimation`, as long as you know this is the type actually used:

```
var opacityAnimation = (DoubleAnimation)timeline;
```

`From` and `To` are then normal dependency properties (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimation.fromproperty) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimation.toproperty)). This means accessing their value works exactly the same way as with any other control's property.

In code you just do:

```
var fromValue = opacityAnimation.From;
var toValue = opacityAnimation.To;
```

To access the animation simpler, you can add a `x:Name` attribute to the animation itself in XAML:

```
<DoubleAnimation x:Name="MyAnimation" ... />
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Happy coding :-)